# anchor inside a li getting all space

Tags: css

I have an anchor inside a li and I want all the li be a link.
How can I change my code to make all the space of li be clicable?

```css
#MenuEventos {
    text-align:center;
}

#MenuEventos li{
    display: block;
    text-align:left;   
    width: 100%;
    margin: 8px 0 8px 0;
    padding: 12px;
} 

#MenuEventos li.vermelho, li.vermelho a{
    background-color: #A9462F;
}
#MenuEventos li.roxo, li.roxo a{
    background-color: #77369C;
} 
#MenuEventos li.azul, li.azul a{
    background-color: #595CC7;
} 
#MenuEventos li.verde, li.verde a{
    background-color: #5E9158;
}

    #MenuEventos li a {
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
        line-height: 2.8em;
        color: white;
        width: 100%;      
        padding: 12px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="MenuEventos">
    <h1 class="MenuEventos">Selecione uma das opções abaixo:</h1>
    <ul id="MenuEventos" class="Menu">
        <li class="vermelho">
            <a href="@Href("~/AreaLogada/Mensal")">Mensal</a>
        </li>
        <li class="roxo">
            <a href="@Href("~/AreaLogada/PorArea")">Por Área</a>
        </li>    
        <li class="azul">
            <a href="@Href("~/AreaLogada/Feriados")">Feriados 2012</a>
        </li>
        <li class="verde">
            <a href="@Href("~/AreaLogada/MeusEventos")">Meus Eventos</a>
        </li>    
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't dump JSFiddle links into your question. Use the in-site code hosting provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest means is to assign `display: block` to the `a` element (so it takes the full horizontal width of the parent `li`), and apply margin/padding to the `a` instead of the `li`.

[JS Fiddle proof-of-concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jvN7z/2/) (Note that I've used the `::before` pseudo element to demonstrate the `a` elements' `hover` state, without having to assign a specific colour to each element's hover state).

Comment: what's the default display for a element?

Comment: The default for an `a` is `display: inline;`

Comment: Is there difference using :before or ::before?

Comment: Not so much, the W3 use the double-colon, `::` to indicate pseudo-elements, to differentiate from pseudo-classes is all.

Comment: Please, just one more thing. I've added a background image to #MenuEventos li a and the before element is wider. It increased in horizontal the same pixels of the background image.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a couple years old and there is already a very good answer, but just wanted to throw out the other possibility of using `display: inline-block;` on the `a` element if you (or anyone) happens to be trying to make a horizontal nav bar. I noticed using `display: block;` forces a new line under the tag and could make your link have some extra space on the bottom, which is undesirable if you're trying to keep your nav bar at a certain height.